# aggregate functions with joined tables. Why do these project different customer ids?

Tags: mysql

I'm playing around with sakila database (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html) to learn SQL, and ran into something that I don't understand. I'm constructing a query that sums customer payments, counts how many payments were made, and projects this information back along with the customers' ids and names.

First, I coded it by using an inner join, and this gave me correct results

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.first_name, SUM(p.amount) total, COUNT(p.amount) n_payments
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN payment p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id
ORDER BY n_payments DESC;
```

[image]

I then wanted to try to answer the same question, but with a different query style, and somehow

1. I'm getting different results
2. I get different ids depending on if I use c.customer_id or p.customer_id to SELECT.

The following is the query in question:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.first_name, SUM(p.amount) total, COUNT(p.amount) n_payments
FROM customer c, payment p
WHERE c.customer_id = p.payment_id
GROUP BY p.customer_id
ORDER BY n_payments DESC;
```

and this is the output that it produces

[image]

Can someone explain why the second query produces incorrect result? Also, in the second query, why does using `SELECT c.customer_id, c.first_name` produce completely different ids / names, compared to `SELECT p.customer_id, p.first_name`?

Comment: When you stop to think about it, it seems fantastically unlikely that a customer_id would equal a payment_id, except by random coincidence.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice what I did there. Thank you @Strawberry !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inadventently changed:

```
c.customer_id = p.customer_id
```

to:

```
c.customer_id = p.payment_id
```

But re using a different query style, don't.  The comma cross join syntax is very old and deprecated.